# Is there a method of rebinding a key on a per-application basis in Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I switched from Windows to Linux on my school laptop a few months ago and I'm loving it, I'm using Arch Linux with i3 as my window manager. I have found ways to do most of the things I used to do on windows in Linux but one thing I quite haven't figured out yet is how to rebind keystrokes per application.

In windows I used a software called AutoHotKey which let me rebind or make scripts that would run on keystrokes depending on which window is active. For example in Brave I rebound capslock to Alt+D which let me focus the adress bar by simply pressing capslock. Note that this wouldn't make sense in other applications which is why I only rebound it in Brave. I am looking for a way to do this in Linux where I can rebind specific keys to other things but only when a specific application is open. I have heard about xdotool which lets you detect active windows etc but haven't found a way to rebind keys.

Comment: Talking about AutoHotKey, there is [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey), the X11 equivalent.

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan Thanks! Will look into it. Will it let me rebind keys?